# Converter um IPAddress para string

Tags: c#, .net, string, socket, conversão-de-tipo

Este código obtém o *gateway* padrão, porém eu não consigo converter o resultado para *string* e colocar em um `label`.

```
public static IPAddress GetDefaultGateway()
{
    var card = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault();
    if(card == null) return null;
    var address = card.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.FirstOrDefault();
    return address.Address;
}
```

Estou tentando assim:

```
IPAddress gatway;
gatway = GetDefaultGateway();
if(gatway != null)
{
    label8.Text = gatway.Address.ToString(); //Aqui da erro...
}
```

Comment: Qual erro que ocorre?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Não há suporte para a operação tentada para o tipo de objeto a que é feita referência

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa propriedade é obsoleta. Utilize o método [`GetAddressBytes()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Net_IPAddress_GetAddressBytes) que retornará um *array* de bytes com cada parte do IP. Depois é só dar um [`Join()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Object___) para formar o texto. Algo assim (usando LINQ):

```
IPAddress gateway = GetDefaultGateway();
if (gateway != null) {
    label8.Text = string.Join(".", gateway.GetAddressBytes().Select(x => x.ToString()));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetGateway.cs).

Se a informação não é a que deseja, o problema é diferente do que está na pergunta e uma nova deve ser feita. Respondi o que resolve o que foi perguntado.

Comment: Estou querendo aquele ip do roteador. Ex: 192.168.0.1(esse é o meu)

Comment: Isso ai parece que da a máscada

Answer (score 1):

Tenta atribuir o texto da label da seguinte maneira:
    `string n = Convert.ToString(gatway.Address);`
    `label8.Text = n;`

Comment: Eu consegui de outra forma porém está retornando o IPV6 e eu quero IPV4